# Split Columns into Sections

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I go about splitting whole columns into sections:

What I want to achieve in the end is to show/hide the column section based on a button using javascript.

The code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th> <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->   
    <th>Shown Content</th>    <!-- This column is meant to be shown --> 
    <th>Hidden Content</th>    <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <th>Action</th> <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->   
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>          <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->   
    <td>Shown</td>      <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <td>Hidden</td>     <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <td><form action='action'><button>VIEW</button></form></td> <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "section"? You can't really hide part of a column because then you'd end up with a blank space above or below the part that was not hidden - is that what you want? Or are you just asking how to hide an entire column, and then how to show the entire column?

Comment: No i meant showing/hiding whole column(s)

Comment: Is it always just one specific column, e.g., the third column, or do you need to be able to hide any column?

Comment: I need to hide a few columns e.g. columns 2 to 20

Comment: I attempted to use `<colgroup>` and `<col style='display:hide;'>` but it didn't work

Comment: `hide` isn't a valid option for `display`. Did you try `display: none`?

Comment: Ahh, sorry I accidently typed in hide in my comment even though in my code I wrote none. And yes it doesn't work.

    `<colgroup>  

            <col colspan='8'></col>  

     <col colspan='20' style='display:none;'>  

    </col></colgroup>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explained:

- On button click, call the toggle function
- Assume any arguments you pass to it are the column numbers; this will need to be amended if you have other requirements (like a range of numbers)
- Using the `nth-child` you're able to select those header and data elements of the supplied column number
- Look at the first one to see if it already has hidden.  This is performed outside the loop because you don't need to check each element, just one since you're applying the class to all the elements
- Once you have the set of data (stored in `col`), iterate over them and either add or remove the class.  CSS is responsible for hiding

Caveats:

This code is heavily reliant on ES6, it can be converted, but you should be especially careful of:

- the arrow functions (`=>`)
- backticks for string interpolation (`` `${variable}` ``)
- the array spread operator `[...obj]`

```js
function toggle() {
  let className = 'hidden';
  [...arguments].forEach(num => {

    var selector = `th:nth-child(${num}), td:nth-child(${num})`,
      col = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
      add = !col[0].classList.contains(className);

    col.forEach(td => {
      add ? td.classList.add(className) : td.classList.remove(className);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <th>Shown Content</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <th>Hidden Content</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <th>Action</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <td>Shown</td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <td>Hidden</td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <td>
      <form action='action'><button>VIEW</button></form>
    </td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
  </tr>

</table>

<button onclick="toggle(1,3)">Toggle</button>
```

Comment: Nice work. This could easily be enhanced for `toggle(3,4,5)` (or `toggle([3,4,5])`, to meet the OP's requirement to hide multiple columns (which was mentioned in a comment).

Comment: Ahh yes, let me try this one it looks like what I wanted

Comment: Just a note that if you need to support many legacy browsers, take heed to the caveats listed above.  ES6 isn't fully supported, so you may need to run it with Babel first.

Answer (score 0):

One line of jQuery

```js
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
  //hide third column with header, you can add more columns if you wish
  $('td:nth-child(3),th:nth-child(3)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <th>Shown Content</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <th>Hidden Content</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <th>Action</th>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <td>Shown</td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <td>Hidden</td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <td>
      <form action='action'><button>VIEW</button></form>
    </td>
    <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
  </tr>

</table>

<button id="hide">Hide Third Column</button>
```

Comment: jQuery does make it easy, but, as the "JavaScript" tag's description says, "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

this to show/hide a column in a specific row

```js
function toggle(){
  var header = document.getElementById('headerHide');
  var parent = document.getElementById('first');
  var sub = parent.querySelector('#hide');
  var btn = parent.querySelector('#btn');
  
  if(sub.style.display == 'none'){
    sub.style.display = 'block';
    header.style.display = 'block';
    btn.innerHTML = "HIDE";
  }
  else{
    sub.style.display = 'none';
    header.style.display = 'none';
    btn.innerHTML = "VIEW";
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th> <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->   
    <th id="headerShow">Shown Content</th>    <!-- This column is meant to be shown --> 
    <th id="headerHide" style="display:none;">Hidden Content</th>    <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <th>Action</th> <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->   
  </tr>

  <tr id="first">
    <td>1</td>          <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->   
    <td id="show">Shown</td>      <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
    <td id="hide" style="display:none;">Hidden</td>     <!-- This column is meant to be hidden -->
    <td><form action='something' style='display:inline'><button onclick="toggle()" id="btn">VIEW</button></form></td> <!-- This column is meant to be shown -->
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `parent.querySelector('#hide')` - a class would be better than an ID, bearing in mind that the same ID should not be used in multiple rows.

Comment: I don't need specific rows since I'm doing this for an inventory system. What I need is to show or hide whole columns without constantly putting id for every column/row